# How to install older version of MonoTouch?

Tags: macos, xamarin.ios, installation, version

I've run into a problem with MonoTouch. I was developing in MonoDevelop as usual, when update screen popped-up, and I've complied, and let it install updates, and restart MonoDevelop. But as soon as I've tried to compile the project for iPhone. It complained, that my license has expired. I've checked, and it was unfortunately correct. So I've checked for my options, and tried new free MonoTouch option first, but that failed to install because my Mac OS X being only version **10.6.7**.

So I fall back to option of reinstalling the older image (monotouch-full.dmg) of MonoTouch, but it is too smart, and tries to install new **6.0.10** (full) not the old version. And probably because of this, or because of a different reason, the installer unfortunately fails to install too:

```
Process: MonoTouchInstaller
Version: 2.0.1
Code Type: X86 (Native)

EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT) 
KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000000000000

abort() called
```

What should I do? How to install the older version of MonoTouch on Mac OS X **10.6.7**. It worked well before I've tried to update it. I don't believe the license ended, and I can't develop anymore. It should be only lack of ability to retrieve newer versions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login into http://store.xamarin.com

Then to go "Manage Subscriptions".

You should see the status of your license here, as well as old versions to download (under Downloads-View All Versions).

Comment: My license has expired. And I have older (in fact the first) download available, but I've described the old download tries to install latest version as well. Do the downloads in the store contain some different version of installer, that installs only the version it indicates?

Comment: Turn off automatic updates after you install, there should be a checkbox in the popup that appears.

Comment: The problem is that it won't install. It fails (as indicated in question) to install, probably because even the old original installer (which worked year before) tries to install new 6.0.10 version, and fails.

Comment: I see the option to install monotouch-6.0.6.pkg - this should be monotouch only and not the full installer. Did you try doing that?

Comment: Not yet, this option is in the Xamarin store? (I'm need to contact our admin guy first, as I'm not the one handling these accounts, and I can't look myself)

Comment: I would go look at the website with him and download any *.pkg files that are available.

Comment: Thanks, I will do just that. I will report the results.

Comment: Hi, so I've finally obtained the file, and unfortunately it did minimum operating system check (Lion 10.7). I'll try to request older version still. Unless you've got other suggestion. It will take hopefully less long.

Comment: There was a certain point they dropped Snow Leopard support.  I would just upgrade to Mountain Lion, its $30 and will make your life easier.

Comment: OK, I'll try to find that point. Unfortunately OSX upgrade is not an available option. Thank you for your answer.